# Difference between 'Niceness' and 'Goodness' in linux kernel 2.4.27

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I am trying to understand linux kernel code for task scheduler.
I am not able to figure out what is goodness value and how it differs from niceness?
Also, how each of them contribute to scheduling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK: Each process in the run queue is assigned a "**goodness**" value which determines how good a process is for running. This value is calculated by the **goodness()** function.

The process with higher goodness will be the next process to run. If no process is available for running, then the operating system selects a special **idle task**.

A first-approximation of **"goodness"** is calculated according to the number of ticks left in the process quantum. This means that the **goodness of a process decreases with time, until it becomes zero when the time quantum of the task expires.**

The final goodness is calculated in function of the niceness of the process. **So basically goodness of a process is a combination of the Time slice left logic and nice value.**

```
static inline int goodness(struct task_struct * p, int this_cpu, struct mm_struct *this_mm)
{
        int weight;

        /*
         * select the current process after every other
         * runnable process, but before the idle thread.
         * Also, dont trigger a counter recalculation.
         */

        weight = -1;
        if (p->policy & SCHED_YIELD)
                goto out;
        if (p->policy == SCHED_OTHER) {
                /*
                 * Give the process a first-approximation goodness value
                 * according to the number of clock-ticks it has left.
                 *
                 * Don't do any other calculations if the time slice is
                 * over..
                 */
                weight = p->counter;
                if (!weight)
                        goto out;
                ...
                weight += 20 - p->nice;
                goto out;
        }

        /* code for real-time processes goes here */

  out:
        return weight;
}
```

TO UNDERSTAND and REMEMBER NICE value: remember this.

The etymology of Nice value is that a "nicer" process allows for more time for other processes to run, hence lower nice value translates to higher priority.

So,

```
Higher the goodness value -> More likely to Run
    Higher the nice value  -> Less likely to run.
```

Also Goodness value is calculated using the nice value as

```
20 - p->nice
```

Since nice value ranges from **-20 ( highest priority) to 19 ( lowest priority)**

```
lets assume a nice value of -20 ( EXTREMELY NOT NICE). hence 20 - (-20) = 40
```

Which means the goodness value has increased, hence this process will be chosen.

Comment: Thanks! It is really useful :)