# goodness value of static and dynamic processes

Tags: process, linux-kernel, operating-system, scheduling

I have a question to ask. First one being, how is goodness value of static and dynamic processes calculated. I read it on a website that (i am re quoting the exact words) ..."The Linux scheduler is a priority based scheduler that schedules tasks based upon their static and dynamic priorities. When these priorities are combined they form a task's goodness ". So how is this combined goodness calculated. Because in the running process queue, both static and dynamic processes will be present.
This question is different frm another question [Difference between 'Niceness' and 'Goodness' in linux kernel 2.4.27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313300/difference-between-niceness-and-goodness-in-linux-kernel-2-4-27)

I am asking about, how is goodness value calculated for static nd dynamic processes.

Comment: If the question was already asked then add a link to that/those question(s) and tell what is missing in e.g. [difference between niceness and goodness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313300) otherwise people will likely wast their time giving the same answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 'Niceness' and 'Goodness' in linux kernel 2.4.27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313300/difference-between-niceness-and-goodness-in-linux-kernel-2-4-27)

Comment: An explanation is in the given link. It is not about static and dynamic processes but about static and dynamic priorities. Niceness is a static value, goodness a dynamic value. Goodess is a weight that is used to determin which process is run next.